# RSL caching not working on Flash Player

Tags: flash, apache-flex, pdf, caching, rsl

We have built a Flex application compiled into an swf file that uses RSL linkage for the different framework libraries it needs. This has been done to reduce the size of the swf file. We are using the URL of the signed version of the library while building the application. The online documentation suggests that the signed SWZ files are cached by the flash player, so that they are not downloaded every time they are required. The swf file is embedded in a PDF file. Our observation is that when we run the Flex application by opening the PDF file in Adobe reader, the RSLs are not getting cached in the Flash player. If we disable the network connection on the computer that opens the PDF file, the Flex application dosen't load. Is this the expected behavior? Or are we missing something? Although if we open this this FLEX application in browser, it works fine.

Is there a way in which we can maintain RSL caching in flash player, so that the PDF can be opened in the offline mode as well.

We welcome your suggestions on this.